# Website Navigation - Slide Down Page Content - Similar to example site 'pavilionvenue.co.uk' but horizontal

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I have a client who wants a website similar to this site here and it's use of showing the page content: http://pavilionvenue.co.uk/, see how the content slides in and out? But they want it to be horizontal instead.

See I've been looking on Google for what it may be called, but i'm not really getting any good results! I would do it on separate pages, but they require the slide out effect, unfortunately, I can't find it!

Could someone tell me a name for this technique please or could someone provide me with some examples?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just animate the height of the corresponding element instead of the width.

I'm not sure if you can find a corresponding "plugin/template" somewhere. I guess you would have to learn javascript/jquery and build it yourself.